# Copy form input from another Component's form - React Hook Form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, watch, react-hook-form

I have two React components that have identical form fields. There is a checkbox that should mirror the input from the form in the other component if it is checked.

The same concept as "same address as billing" functionality but the forms are in separate components.

I'm trying to use React Hook Form's "watch" but I'm not sure how to pass the input from Component: FormOne to Component: FormTwo.

Here's my code: [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-clarke-9m8bo?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: Is it a requirement that you need to separate the inputs into two forms? For semantic reasons (and also to make it much simpler) there should be only one form element for your page, as the two fields in a way also belong to each other.

Comment: @knoefel I'm only making modifications to an existing app and these forms that will share data are only small parts of the (form) components that they are in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `useForm` multiple times, you can't use RHF's provided `<FormProvider />`.

So basically you have the following options:

- refactor your `<Form />` components, that they all will use the same methods returned by `useForm` by using RHF's `<FormProvider />` instead of defining `useForm` for every `<Form />` component.
- use React's Context API so you can access the form state in every child `<Form />` component
- pass values and setters using props

Here is a CodeSandbox using RHF's `<FormProvider /`>:

[image: Edit condescending-antonelli-18wv3]

Here is a CodeSandbox using Context API:

[image: Edit gallant-sea-irdbc]

Comment: Thanks! How come the data that is being logged on the console is for the second form field only when I submit the form?

Comment: Your submit button is part of `<FormTwo />`, so `onSubmit`, only the fields, which are registered in `<FormTwo />` will be included. That's why i suggested to only use 1 `useForm`, then you would have access to all registered fields. So for now and if you don't want to refactor all components, you should use the `Context` value of your form values, when submitting. Here is an updated [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-smoke-gtidt?file=/src/FormTwo.tsx)

Comment: I updated my answer showing you the preferred approach to handle this situation. All you have to refactor is to add RHF's `<FormProvider />` and use RHF's methods via the `useFormContext` hook. This way you can pass the `defaultValues` at the parent level instead of passing all of them via props.